# Symfony/Doctrine - relations between order, order_item and product

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm sorry but I don't understand something with relation many to one.

I've got 3 tables:

- Order
- Order Item
- Product

and the relations are:

- Order has a relation with Order Item, one to many
- OrderItem ha a relation with Product, many to one

The product exists in the database (like an ecommerce). When the customer selects the product, a shopping cart is created. Then I persist and flush the cart (it's the Order entity).

But I've got this message:

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\OrderItem#product' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Entity\Product@911. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'App\Entity\Product#__toString()' to get a clue.
```

The problem is: if I add this cascade option, doctrine will add a new product. But the product exists already. I don't want to add a new product. I just want to say to my database:

> Hey bro, add a new line in order table and a new line into order_item
> table. In order_item table, I've got a product, his id is 1234.

I guess I'm wrong somewhere but I don't where..

Thanks for helping me ✌️

Edit:

In my product page, when the customer add the product in the cart:

```php
$orderItem = $form->getData();
$orderItem->setProduct($product);
$cart->addItem($orderItem);
```

and addItem function:

```php
public function addItem(OrderItem $item): self
{
        foreach ($this->getItems() as $existingItem) {
            if ($existingItem->equals($item)) {
                $quantity = $existingItem->getQuantity() + $item->getQuantity();
                $product = $item->getProduct();
                if ($quantity > $product->getQuantity()) {
                    $quantity = $product->getQuantity();
                }
                $existingItem->setQuantity($quantity);

                return $this;
            }
        }

        $this->items[] = $item;
        $item->setOrderRef($this);

        return $this;
}
```

If I dump $cart, I saw OrderItem and for one OrderItem there's a product with the correct ID

Edit 2:

I skipped somes attributes

OrderItem entity:

```php
    /**
     * @Expose
     * @Type("App\Entity\Product")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Product::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Order::class, inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $orderRef;
```

Order Entity:

```php
    /**
     * @Expose
     * @Type("ArrayCollection<App\Entity\OrderItem>")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=OrderItem::class, mappedBy="orderRef", cascade={"persist","remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $items;
```

Comment: How are you setting the product for the order item? If it isn't fetched using the ORM, then even if it is identical to an existing one, Doctrine will try to create a new product

Comment: @ChrisHaas I edited my main post for more details

Comment: For `$orderItem->setProduct($product);`, is that item still directly fetched from the ORM, it hasn't been serialized in anyway?

Comment: @ChrisHaas directly from ORM (param converter) but you tell me something I missed to say. Order, is saved into the user session. To be ligher, I serialized the object. When the user is on the shopping cart, I deserialized the object , string to Order entity.

Comment: Serialization breaks the ORM relationship, you need to re-fetch it. There is a merge operation to reattach, but I think it is marked as deprecated (although I think it has been marked like that for many years now)

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for the tips, I'll try tomorrow and I keep you up to date 

Comment: @ChrisHaas I tried many things tonight but idk what's wrong with JMS Serializer 

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “what's wrong with JMS Serializer”? You need to re-fetch the entity when you associate with another entity for insertion or update, otherwise Doctrine thinks it is a new one. The object’s ID doesn’t really mean anything to Doctrine, it is the object itself that it is tracking.

Comment: In my comment below, you will see my solution. Quickly, after deserialization, my object is cloned (using __clone method) and I add each items on the fresh object.

Comment: One thing you might want to consider is separating entities which are generally for Doctrine to manage, and other things that happen to hold data, which are commonly called DTOs. Here's a [very basic example](https://3v4l.org/6vuZN). The interface is optional, but sometimes it helps if you have methods that could act on either. The DTO can be serialized very-light weight and intentionally does not have an ID since it isn't in the database. You can convert from the DTO to an Entity using the static function on the Entity (or a `toEntity()` method on the DTO).

Answer (score 0):

For me you miss the relation (or maybe I did not understand clearly).
Oder must have multiple Product.
So that mean:

- Order must have multiple OrderItem
- Product must have multiple OrderItem
- OrderItem must have one Order and one Product (OneToMany for both Entity)

Then you could add cascade persist to relation Order->OrderItem and that should work.
The product must absolutely come from Doctrine when you create objects Order and OrderItem. So his ID must be set.

Comment: Hi, you will find in the initial post my entities. But I don't thing the problem comes from here. The problem comes from the serialization (jms), I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Damn man! You never talk about any serialization in you main post! How are we supposed to know that?

Comment: Yeah sure! I'm sorry, it's in my comment above 

Comment: Ok I guess in some old version of Symfony you could try to use $entityManager->merge($product). But I don't know if it's still exist on your version. Because when you serialize an object, you normally detached it from EntityManager context. So Doctrine could see it as a new object. See: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities

Comment: unfortunately, merge is now deprecated. And I cannot find the entity by id and then set the new value because my entity is not saved into the db. My workaround has been to implement __clone method into my Order entity. When I deserialized my object, I clone $order ($cart = clone $order) then I get order_items from $order, iterate on each one and I set $cart->addItem($item)
This solution works, maybe not the gorgeous one but its works...

Comment: Which entity is not saved into your database? Product?